# jquery, js: how to read specific line from external file?

Tags: jquery, file, external

How do you read a specific line, say line 3, from an external file using jquery or javascript?

many thanks.

Comment: thanks. maybe txt or html file.

Comment: Where might this file be located?

Comment: You mean on server or file system ? 
if server you can use ajax to do this , if on file system as i know you cant do it using standard javascript .

Comment: sorry, i was a little vague.  I am trying to create a web app using html5 and jquery mobile.  I have huge list of qoutations and they're listed in one file(txt file & html).  I wanted to read random lines and display it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the file using `jQuery.get`
2. Split the read content by `\n` or `\r\n`
3. Fetch the item for the corresponding row from the resultant array

Comment: Thanks.  This file contains hundreds of lines, do you think it won't crash or slows the process?

Comment: No, I really don't think hundreds of lines would pose a performance burden...

Comment: Hundreds of lines should be trivial. Hundreds of thousands is another story.